# Finding best combination to match budget

Tags: c#

Say I have a list of products like so:

`var products = new List<Product>(){
  new Product{ name="product1", price=200},
  new Product{ name="product2", price=600},
  new Product{ name="product3", price=300},
  new Product{ name="product4", price=250}
];`

What is a good approach if I want to find the best combination of products given a arbitrary "budget"?

- I want to come as close as possible to the budget, but not over.
- Its ok if a product appear multiple times.

Comment: Knapsack problem?

Comment: Best is a bit vague. Is the goal to find a way to spend as much as possible?

Comment: It's the subset sum problem, as it has not both weight and value.

Comment: @Charles wouldn't that be if there was both weight and value, rather than just value in my case?

Comment: @DavidW. the value for your case is just 1 for all, it's a special case, but still Knapsack

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras, subset sum is to find a subset that sums up to the number, it doesn't allow repetition, and it doesn't say it needs to find the lowest possible next if it couldn't find the exact sum

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras yes, target is to "come as close as possible to the budget"

Comment: I am having trouble answering this question because it is obvious (now that @Charles has intelligently pointed it out) that there are algorithms out there for the OP to find. I don't know what value I could add by writing an answer here. Is there a more specific question?